# PHP Mysql not working correctly echo inner join

Tags: php, html, mysql

Why isn't this code echoing anything
I really hope you can help me :)
Its for my site.

Table structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrRKC.jpg

```
<?php
$q = mysql_query("SELECT user_1_id AS user1, users2.username AS user2, firewind_trades.id, firewind_trades.timestamp
                FROM `firewind_trades`
                INNER JOIN `users` users1 on firewind_trades.1id = users1.id
                INNER JOIN `users` users2 on firewind_trades.2id = users2.id
                ORDER BY id DESC;");
while ($m = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { 
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td >'.$m['id'].'</td>
        <td >'.$m['user1'].'</td>
        <td >'.$m['user2'].'</td>
        <td >'.$m['timestamp'].'</td>
        <td ><a href="index.php?url=hk&tradelogs&id='.$m['id'].'">Vis byttehandel</a></td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: please add the table structure.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/M6Y9t

Answer (score 0):

If you lunch your request in mySQL client do you have results? Because I don't see these fields `firewind_trades.1id` and `firewind_trades.2id` into firewind_trades table.

Maybe you can try :

```
INNER JOIN `users` users1 on firewind_trades.user_1_id = users1.id
INNER JOIN `users` users2 on firewind_trades.user_2_id = users2.id
```

Comment: Hmm.. My code works but it is not showing the "items" traded when going to &id=TRADE ID


Furthermore it shows up like this: http://imgur.com/a/LEIgO  (it needs to show user1(username) and user2(username) user2username is working as you can see on the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issues in the select & join fields.
Try this:

```
 <?php
$q = mysql_query("SELECT users1.username AS user1, users2.username AS user2, firewind_trades.id, firewind_trades.timestamp
            FROM `firewind_trades`
            INNER JOIN `users` users1 on firewind_trades.user_1_id = users1.id
            INNER JOIN `users` users2 on firewind_trades.user_2_id = users2.id
            ORDER BY id DESC;");
while ($m = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
echo '
<tr>
    <td >'.$m['id'].'</td>
    <td >'.$m['user1'].'</td>
    <td >'.$m['user2'].'</td>
    <td >'.$m['timestamp'].'</td>
    <td ><a href="index.php?url=hk&tradelogs&id='.$m['id'].'">Vis byttehandel</a></td>
</tr>
';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hmm.. My code works but it is not showing the "items" traded when going to &id=TRADE ID


Furthermore it shows up like this: http://imgur.com/a/LEIgO  (it needs to show user1(username) and user2(username) user2username is working as you can see on the picture.